# Downloading libraries in the virtual env on button click in QGIS Plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am creating a plugin in QGIS 3.24 using Python.
i want to install the libraries such as numpy, pandas, etc on the click of a button in Plugin which will in turn download the libraries in the virtual environment created in VS code.
is it possible using Python?

The below code downloads the library in the system, I want to download it in the virtual environment.

```
 import subprocess
 try:
     import numpy
 except ModuleNotFoundError:
     subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', 'numpy'])
     print(" done")
```

Basically , I have created a venv in VSCode. I have built a plug-in where i created a clickable btn which will install libraries. now the problem is that I want to install the library in the venv and not in any other location.

Comment: Then you would need to launch QGIS with the same virtual environment as the one you use in VS code. And that sounds like an invitation to load of breakage and problems to me. Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: Whats best way according to you?

Comment: What depends on what you are really trying to solve ;) Do you need numpy etc available in the environment that QGIS runs in?

Comment: I will edit the requirement in the question .